# Display XML column data from pivot as individual columns

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, pivot

I have a table that is structured,

> Columns: month_yyyy, account_id, account_name, revenue

I'd like to pivot the data in table so it's displayed as

> Columns: account_id, account_name, month_yyyy1 (revenue), month_yyyy2 (revenue)... monthyyyy_n (revenue)

I did this,

```
    select * from ( 
SELECT month_yyyy,
       account_id,
       account_name,
       revenue
  FROM table
   order by to_date(month_yyyy, 'month yyyy')
)
pivot xml(
    sum (revenue) as revenue for (month_yyyy) in (select distinct month_yyyy from table) 
  ) 
order by account_name;
```

This gives data like for the pivoted xml column,

```
<PivotSet><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">April 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">August 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">December 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">Decmber 2011</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">February 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">February 2013</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">January 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">January 2013</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">July 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">June 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">March 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">March 2013</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">May 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">November 2011</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">November 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">October 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item><item><column name = "MONTH_YYYY">September 2012</column><column name = "REVENUE">0</column></item></PivotSet>
```

How do i create a view that selects and displays the xml column data as individual columns by month? I want to achieve,

> account_id, account_name, month_yyyy1 (revenue), month_yyyy2 (revenue)... monthyyyy_n (revenue)

Thanks for any assistance given and please let me know if further info is required.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can't use the pivot with a select in the IN clause.

[I tested it](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c42c9d/8) on sql fiddle and you need to give a list of values to pivot on. Maybe you could use a pl/sql function to convert a result column to a comma separated list, but not sure if that would be usable by pivot.

```
create table tab
( month_yyyy varchar2(20)
, account_id number
, account_name varchar2(20)
, revenue number
);

insert into tab values ('januari_2013', 1, 'acc one', 10);
insert into tab values ('januari_2013', 2, 'acc two', 20);
insert into tab values ('februari_2013', 1, 'acc one', 100);
insert into tab values ('februari_2013', 2, 'acc two', 200);
insert into tab values ('march_2013', 1, 'acc one', 1000);
insert into tab values ('march_2013', 2, 'acc two', 2000);

select *
from   tab
-- this does not work: pivot ( sum(revenue) FOR month_yyyy IN (select distinct month_yyyy from tab) )
-- this works:
pivot ( sum(revenue) FOR month_yyyy IN ('januari_2013', 'februari_2013', 'march_2013') )
```

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I found an alternate approach to my problem. You can use a pivot in a select tho see http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php.